# one hot encoding dirty column in R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column like so. The column begins and ends with a ',' and each value is separated by ',,'.

```
col1
,101,,9,,201,,200,
,201,,101,,102,
,9,,101,,102,,200,,201,
,101,,200,,9,,102,,102,
```

How can i transform this column into the following:

```
col1_9 col1_101 col1_102 col1_200 col1_201
1      1        0        1        1
0      1        1        0        1
1      1        1        1        1
1      1        2        1        0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df%>%
  mutate(rowid = row_number(), value = 1)%>%
  separate_rows(col1)%>%
  filter(nzchar(col1)) %>%
  pivot_wider(rowid, names_from = col1, 
              values_fn = sum, names_prefix = 'col1_', 
              values_fill = 0)

  # A tibble: 4 x 6
  rowid col1_101 col1_9 col1_201 col1_200 col1_102
  <int>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1        1      1        1        1        0
2     2        1      0        1        0        1
3     3        1      1        1        1        1
4     4        1      1        0        1        2
```

in Base R:

```
a <- setNames(strsplit(trimws(df$col1,white=','), ',+'), seq(nrow(df)))
as.data.frame.matrix(t(table(stack(a))))

  101 102 200 201 9
1   1   0   1   1 1
2   1   1   0   1 0
3   1   1   1   1 1
4   1   2   1   0 1
```

Comment: is there a way to order the colnames by the number?

Comment: @Eisen in the base R oprion, store the results in a variable `b` then do `b[,order(as.numeric(names(b)))]`

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: @Eisen what do you mean? did you do `b <- as.data.frame.matrix(t(table(stack(a))))` then run the code `b[,order(as.numeric(names(b)))]`? What error do you get?

Comment: i dont get an error but it doesn't sort the columns correctly they shoudl be sorted the same way in my example output

Comment: @Eisen yes the base R does sort them the way you have in your output. The code clearly works. Check again. Unless your names are not the same as the ones that are there is the output I have. in that case you will have to do `b[, as.character(str_sort(names(b), numeric = TRUE))]`

Comment: what exactly does the filter on nzchar do?

Comment: @Eisen remove empty rows

Answer (score 0):

An option could be:

- First remove the "," at begin and end using `str_sub` from `stringr`
- One Hot encode the column using `mtabulate` and `strsplit` with sep of ",,"
- Order the column names based on number
- Finally, give the columns the "col1_" names using `paste0`

Which gives this as result:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "col1
,101,,9,,201,,200,
,201,,101,,102,
,9,,101,,102,,200,,201,
,101,,200,,9,,102,,102,", header = TRUE)

library(stringr)
library(qdapTools)
df$col1 <- str_sub(df$col1, 2, -2)
df <- mtabulate(strsplit(df$col1, ",,"))
df <- df[, order(as.numeric(names(df)))]
names(df) <- paste0("col1_", names(df))
df
#>   col1_9 col1_101 col1_102 col1_200 col1_201
#> 1      1        1        0        1        1
#> 2      0        1        1        0        1
#> 3      1        1        1        1        1
#> 4      1        1        2        1        0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>